# Error: bad port during put port range

Tags: security, ufw

I try to allow port using `ufw` like below but `error:bad port` appears

```
test:~# sudo ufw allow 45000:65536/tcp
ERROR: Bad port
```

Answer (score 1):

The "port" field in a packet is only 16 bits long, thus it can hold values from 0 to 65535. Your use of port 65536 in your
command will not fit into 16 bits, and is, therefore, invalid.

Your command should be:

```
sudo ufw allow 45000:65535/tcp
```